# Spring Validation - BindingResult

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I am trying to understand what `BeanPropertyBindingResult` does in the following code. Unfortunately, the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BeanPropertyBindingResult.html#BeanPropertyBindingResult%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) is quite useless.

Please take a look at the following code:

```
BeanPropertyBindingResult errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(item, "item");
validator.validate(item, errors);
```

My questions are:

1. As far as I can see, `BeanPropertyBindingResult` is basically some kind of a `Map` that can contain key/value pairs of (field name, error text). Is this correct, or is the truth more complicated?
2. When I create a new `BeanPropertyBindingResult`, why do I need to provide it (as the constructor's first parameter) with the object I am going to validate? As far as I can see, in the second line above, `validator.validate(item, errors);` the validator gets the object anyway.. so why doing it twice?
3. The javadoc says about the constructor's second parameter:

> objectName - the name of the target object

yes, but why do I need that name? What am I supposed/able to do with it...?

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, that is my understanding too, even if it is technically a list. -- The most importent part is `List<ObjectError> errors` defined in the superclass `AbstractBindingResult`.

2) Because it is demanded by the `BindingResult` Interface. -- *I know this is not a good answer, but If this interfaces requires that method, then ther is no otherway to implement it* BTW: I think I have seen some example before where the Autor used `null` for that field, but I am not 100% if it works correct, but most of the code seams to be able to handle the null value.

3) If you use that binding result for example in a jsp to show the error messages for different input fields, then this must match the model attribute name.

Assume you have a command object with a field `name`. And a JSP page where the input filed is associated to `myCommand.name`. Then you need the name `myCommand` as some kind of prefix for the binding errors. -- *It is hard to explain, I hope you understand what I mean*